# Vulnerabilities of Linux Kernel While Scanning Docker Images in AWS ECR

Tags: docker, debian-based, amazon-ecr

We are using AWS ECR for managing docker images. I enabled "Scan on push" while creating repository. 
We are building the docker images on Linux Kernel which has version of "5.3.0-40-generic".

After Pushing those images to repository, I see a few Critical Vulnerabilities. 
I am getting the Link for every issue. I tried understanding each issue.

If the issue is fixed, they are saying to use the package with different version which is fixed.

How can i install the fixed version while building the docker image?

Comment: What's the specific file/package it's complaining about?  What image are you using?  What have you already tried?

Comment: mercurial:4.0-1+deb9u1 is the package, 
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-17458  is the link.

I am using "node:latest" image

I understood from the link to use another version of package which is "3.1.2-2+deb8u7" not having the vulnerability.